# Wrong encoding display data in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

*I'm sorry if answer on this question already exist, but I couldn't find it*

*Please give me a link if answer already exist.*

I use SQL Server 2008 R2.

When I run a `select` in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Firm COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS
```

I get wrong encoding display data in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

[image: wrong encoding display data in Microsoft SQL Managament Studio]

Tell me please how make that data show in the correct coding?

Comment: Please execute the following statement: `SELECT name, description FROM fn_helpcollations() WHERE name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS';` and tell me if you get a result.
Are you sure this statement works? Normally you have to `ORDER BY` something before you `COLLATE`...

Comment: Please provide the output without collation specified

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with stored data (otherwise the "?" symbols will be returned).
Looks like the problem with fonts in the SQL Server management studio. Check the settings in the menu item

> Tools => Options => Environment => Fonts and Colors (section Grid Results):

[image]